# Changing navigation view header image programmatically is not working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm trying to change the Navigation view's header image on clicking drawer menu icon programmatically but now working. 
How to solve this problem? 
Here's my **DrawerActivity** class`

```
public class DrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(120, 120);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout  drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Here's my **AriesActivity** , on which I'm using drawer menu icon, on clicking drawer has been opened.

```
public class AriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar mtoolbar;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aries);

    //setting TOOLBAR on this activity(page)
    mtoolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle(null);


    //setting DRAWER on this activity(page)
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, mtoolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();


}
```

Here's my **navigation_view.xml** layout file`

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer"
app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_drawer"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    />
```

and finally **nav_view_header.xml** layout file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/background_nav_header"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:id="@+id/headerView">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewNav"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_ring_shape"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
        android:padding="22dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/background_img_nav_0" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/sign_name"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you mean changing `imageViewNav` image in `nav_view_header.xml layout file`?

Comment: ʍѳђઽ૯ท - yeah! if you know then please!!

Answer (score 3):

Add prefix of `NavigationView` before findviewByid or;

```
View header = mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0);
myImageView = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.imageviewname);
myImageView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_drawable));
```

And check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43285072/4409113

Comment: I edited the code according to you but still isn't working.

Comment: Try with this; https://stackoverflow.com/a/16906599/4409113 use `setBackgroundResource`

Comment: this worked for me. Make sure src is not set at ImageView.