# Android: Can't access MenuItem in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make the last MenuItem invisible in the Drawer menu. Despite the [existing solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284754/android-how-to-access-the-navigation-drawer-header-items) on Stackoverflow I get a null pointer exception and don't understand it.

**navdrawer_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/faq_id"
        android:icon="@drawable/contact_support_24px"
        android:title="@string/frequently_asked_questions" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/support_id"
        android:icon="@drawable/email_24px"
        android:title="@string/support_suggestions" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/news_twitter_id"
        android:icon="@drawable/twitter"
        android:title="@string/news_twitter" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/news_facebook_id"
        android:icon="@drawable/facebook_24px"
        android:title="@string/news_facebook" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/signout_id"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
        android:title="@string/sign_out" />
</menu>
```

**Activity layout:**

```
<layout>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        <LinearLayout
            <fragment/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navViewVpn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/navdrawer_menu" />
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

**Activity Code:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navViewVpn)
        val i = navView.headerCount // 1
        val header: View = navView.getHeaderView(0)
        val signout: MenuItem = header.findViewById(R.id.signout_id) // Crash
}
```

The crash is on the last line, it can't even find the signout_id under the header. But why?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.company.App.vpn.android, PID: 12008
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.App.vpn.android/com.company.App.vpn.android.VpnActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: header.findViewById(R.id.signout_id) must not be null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: header.findViewById(R.id.signout_id) must not be null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line, we are trying to assign a View instance to a variable of type *MenuItem*. *MenuItem* does not extend View (and therefore doesn't exist), so this assignment is giving us some trouble.

```
val signout: MenuItem = header.findViewById(R.id.signout_id)
```

Grabbing that *MenuItem* is absolutely on the right track. However, the header element is actually a separate element of the navigation drawer and not useful in this case. Instead, we can get a reference to the *MenuItem* using the `navView` instance. Then, use the `findItem` method, as opposed to `findViewById`.

From there one can programmatically edit the menu item as necessary.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navViewVpn)

        val signout: MenuItem = navView.menu.findItem(R.id.signout_id);
        
        // Edit the menu item as required
        signout.isVisible = false;
}
```

*Note, for anyone doing this in Java, the equivalent code is as follows.*

```
NavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view_id);
MenuItem item = navView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navItemId);
```